# Running Multiple Elevated Cmd Prompts through C#

Tags: c#, windows-7, cmd, admin, scheduler

I'm basically trying to copy all the files from the Tasks folder at `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks` and transfer to any folder of choosing using C#. So far I have this code:

```
String strCmdTxt = "/k %WINDIR%\\sysnative\\cmd.exe && xcopy\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\Tasks\\*.*\" \"C:\\Users\\Blah_Blah\\Documents\\Test\\\" /e /i /h";
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo i = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();//("cmd.exe", strCmdTxt);
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
i.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
i.UseShellExecute =true;
i.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
i.Verb = "runas";
p.StartInfo = i;
try{
    p.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("The folders were copied");
    p.WaitForExit();
    p.Close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine("error");
}
```

So the problem is that this compiles but it doesn't produce what I want.

I use the `i.Verb` to make sure the command runs as an admin so it can access the task's schedule files. In addition I run the `%WINDIR%\\sysnative\\cmd.exe` so the cmd can access the `System32` folder because the cmd opens in `SysWOW64`.

But for some reason the rest of it (`xcopy \"C:\\Windows\\System32\\Tasks\\*.*\" \"C:\\Users\\Kapil_Gowru\\Documents\\Test\\\" /e /i /h`) doesn't seem to run. I've tried doing this task using `StreamWriter` so I can output two separate commands to the cmd, but that voids my ability to run the cmd as an admin.

So I guess what is another possibility to accomplish this? If you have any more questions about my issue, post here and I will reply. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you send the command to the process after you start it, try redirecting `StandardInput` then sending *strCmdTxt*, see this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx) for a sample on using StandardInput

Though I do not understand why you are trying to use a process to start a cmd prompt to copy the files, why don't you just do the file copy directly from C# using good old [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), just start up your app as admin/elevated